# Java EE 6, EJB 3.1, JPA 2.0 - error in inserting record in database

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I am trying to insert a record in the database (using Java EE 6, EJB 3.1, JPA 2.0). I am getting an error that accountTypeId field is null, but i have set it up as autogenerate. Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Following is the create table query:

```
create table example.account_type(
    account_type_id INT NOT null PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    account_type_desc varchar(20)
);
```

Following is the entity class:

EDIT: Updated the entity class as generated by NetBeans which didn't work. I also added @GeneratedValue annotation but still it didn't work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT_TYPE")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "AccountType.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM AccountType a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AccountType.findByAccountTypeId", query = "SELECT a FROM AccountType a WHERE a.accountTypeId = :accountTypeId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AccountType.findByAccountTypeDesc", query = "SELECT a FROM AccountType a WHERE a.accountTypeDesc = :accountTypeDesc")})
public class AccountType implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  // ADDED THIS LINE
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID")
    private Integer accountTypeId;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESC")
    private String accountTypeDesc;

    public AccountType() {
    }

    public AccountType(Integer accountTypeId) {
        this.accountTypeId = accountTypeId;
    }

    public Integer getAccountTypeId() {
        return accountTypeId;
    }

    public void setAccountTypeId(Integer accountTypeId) {
        this.accountTypeId = accountTypeId;
    }

    public String getAccountTypeDesc() {
        return accountTypeDesc;
    }

    public void setAccountTypeDesc(String accountTypeDesc) {
        this.accountTypeDesc = accountTypeDesc;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (accountTypeId != null ? accountTypeId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof AccountType)) {
            return false;
        }
        AccountType other = (AccountType) object;
        if ((this.accountTypeId == null && other.accountTypeId != null) || (this.accountTypeId != null && !this.accountTypeId.equals(other.accountTypeId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entities.AccountType[ accountTypeId=" + accountTypeId + " ]";
    }

}
```

Following is the session bean interface:

```
@Remote
public interface AccountTypeSessionBeanRemote {
    public void createAccountType();
    public void createAccountType(String accDesc);
}
```

Following is the session bean implementation class:

```
@Stateless
public class AccountTypeSessionBean implements AccountTypeSessionBeanRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="ExamplePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void createAccountType(String accDesc) {
        AccountType emp = new AccountType(accDsc);
       try {
           this.em.persist(emp);
           System.out.println("after persist");
       } catch(Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("ex: " + ex.getMessage());
       }
    }
}
```

Following is the Main class:

```
public class Main {
    @EJB
    private static AccountTypeSessionBeanRemote accountTypeSessionBean;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        accountTypeSessionBean.createAccountType("test");
    }
}
```

Following is the error:

```
INFO: ex: Object: Entities.AccountType[ accountTypeId=null ] is not a known entity type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my `create table query` as following:

```
create table example.account_type(
    account_type_id INT NOT null PRIMARY KEY,
    account_type_desc varchar(20)
);
```

Then had to add the following line to the entity class (Netbeans doesn't add that):

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting an error because of "accountTypeId field is null". As the error message says, the error occurs because "Entities.AccountType[ accountTypeId=null ] is not a known entity type".

The most likely reason is that `AccountType` is not annotated with [@Entity](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html). This problem is likely solved by adding it. Additionally it makes sense to use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

instead of AUTO. Auto means that the provider chooses a strategy based on the capabilities of the target database. According to the table definition it seems clear that the preferred strategy is IDENTITY.

Comment: The missing entity annotation may just be cut and paste, but yeah, it should be there if it isn't. But I think your second answer, the GenerationType.IDENTITY, is probably the root cause.

Comment: Thanks all for replying. The missing @Entity annotation was just a copy and paste error. I tried to change the generationtype to identity but that didn't work. I still get the same error.